# What the RL as view by this circuit

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, bjt

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMGPwh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this condition, RL=infinity so the voltage gain of the output at the node R5 and Q1 can be obtain as below

$$A_v=\frac{4800}{450}=10.67$$

Verified with simulator which is in good agreement

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ8dTj.png)</sup>

However, now the output is connected to a bypass capacitor of 5.3micro farad and my simulator showing a gain of only 3, understood as there is current flow into the 5.3micro farad capacitor that pull down the voltage gain and from youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MyVscG-Pew&t=363s I understood the gain is gain is
$$A_v=\frac{4800||R_{effective}}{r_e'+450}$$

Is the $$R_{effective}=R_7||R_8$$ so that theoretical value of $$A_v=3.73$$ or the calculation is actually more complicated than this?

Comment: R8 is loading down the output. Can't you see that?

Comment: How about R7? Isn't in the analysis, the DC supply is replace by a short circuit? This is the part I not sure and need clarification

Comment: R7 is a large value. It doesn't have the same impact. Not even close.

Comment: Also, your added capacitor in the 2nd stage means a heavy load that is even worse that R7.

Comment: Quick unrelated note: If it's not an exercice but something you actually want to build, you should ensure that the component values you choose do exist. (Look at the "E series of preferred numbers" on Wikipedia). Almost all the resistors and capacitors of your design don't exist at theses specific values.

Comment: Thank for clarification, so R7 is in parallel with R8 when consider the load, just the value is too big so when come to approximation ,it can be ignore. I added the bypass capacitor so from the 1st stage it amplified the signal but it is inverted, then send it into the 2nd stage to further amplify and inverted the signal so now it is in phase with the same signal, then using darlington pair to strengthen the signal for 8ohm load. If not adding the capacitor, anyway to separate AC signal with DC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the 2nd stage.

The first thing to do is to work out the DC quiescent point for your 2nd stage. Assuming \$\beta\approx 200\$, I get \$I_{\text{B}_2}=\frac{V_{_\text{TH}}-V_\text{BE}}{R_{_\text{TH}}-\beta\cdot R_\text{E}}\approx 5.5\:\mu\text{A}\$ and therefore \$I_{\text{E}_2}\approx 1.1\:\text{mA}\$. This means \$r_e^{'}\approx 24\:\Omega\$. And if your frequency is \$1\:\text{kHz}\$, then \$X_\text{C}\approx 5.3\:\Omega\$. Reflected back to the base I get about \$5.9\:\text{k}\Omega\$. So the total load on the first stage is about \$5.9\:\text{k}\Omega\mid\mid 26\:\text{k}\Omega\mid\mid 2.9\:\text{k}\Omega\$ or about \$\approx 1.81\:\text{k}\Omega\$. This means that only about 27.4% of the 1st stage voltage gain is retained. About \$27.4\%\cdot 10.67\approx 2.92\$, or so.

Very close to what you measured with simulation.

Comment: How did you calculate 27.4%?

Comment: Thanks, I finally figured it out how you get the 5.9kohm.

Comment: I guess jonk using formula 1/(1/1810+1/4800)/4800=1318/4800*100=27.4

Comment: @chuackt I did forget about the bulk emitter resistance of perhaps a few tenths of an Ohm. My mistake there.